# Getting 422 (Unprocessable Entity) from my react-redux front-end

Tags: react-redux, rails-api, redux-toolkit

I'm sorry I had to rephrase this question because I never knew the issue was coming from my rails-api backend.
When I try to create a lists of `appointments` from my react-redux front-end, I get this error:

```
appointmentsSlice.js:16 POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1/appointments 422 (Unprocessable Entity)
```

Initially, I was able to create a lists of appointments before the error set in. And I didn't make any major changes to both the backend/frontend.

And these are the logs from my rails backend:

```
Started POST "/api/v1/appointments" for ::1 at 2021-08-04 20:53:35 +0100
Processing by AppointmentsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"appointment_date"=>"2021-08-04", "doctor_id"=>"", "user_id"=>20, "appointment"=>{"appointment_date"=>"2021-08-04", "doctor_id"=>"", "user_id"=>20}}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 20], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:28:in `current_user'
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 20], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:28:in `current_user'
Unpermitted parameter: :appointment
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 414ms (Views: 373.9ms | ActiveRecord: 1.1ms | Allocations: 343604)


Started GET "/api/v1/appointments" for ::1 at 2021-08-04 20:53:36 +0100
Processing by AppointmentsController#index as */*
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 20], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:28:in `current_user'
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 20], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:28:in `current_user'
  Appointment Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "appointments".* FROM "appointments" WHERE "appointments"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 20]]
  ↳ app/controllers/appointments_controller.rb:8:in `index'
Completed 200 OK in 8ms (Views: 3.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms | Allocations: 2300)
```

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include Response

  private

  def secret
    Rails.application.secret_key_base
  end

  def encode_token(payload)
    JWT.encode(payload, secret)
  end

  def decoded_token
    auth = request.headers['Authorization']
    if auth
      token = auth.split(' ')[1]
      JWT.decode(token, secret, true, algorithm: 'HS256')
    end
  rescue StandardError
    nil
  end

  def current_user
    return unless decoded_token

    user_id = decoded_token[0]['user_id']
    User.find_by(id: user_id)
  end

  def authorize
    render json: { message: 'Please log in.' }, status: :unauthorized if current_user.nil?
  end
end
```

```
class AppointmentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authorize
  before_action :find_appointment, only: %i[show update destroy]

  def index
    @appointments = current_user.appointments

    render json: @appointments
  end

  def show
    render json: @appointment
  end

  def create
    @appointment = current_user.appointments.build(appointment_params)

    if @appointment.save
      render json: @appointment, status: :created
    else
      render json: @appointment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def update
    if @appointment.update(appointment_params)
      render json: @appointment
    else
      render json: @appointment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @appointment.destroy
    render json: { message: 'Appointment deleted' }, status: :ok
  end

  private

  def find_appointment
    @appointment = Appointment.find(params[:id])
  end

  def appointment_params
    params.permit(:appointment_date, :doctor_id, :user_id)
  end
end
```

src/redux/appointmentsSlice from my react-redux frontend

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import API from '../api/api';

export const postAppointments = createAsyncThunk(
  'appointments/postAppointments',
  async (
    {
      user_id, appointment_date, doctor_id,
    },
  ) => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    const response = await fetch(`${API}/appointments`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Accept: 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },

      body: JSON.stringify({
        appointment_date,
        doctor_id,
        user_id,
      }),
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    if (!response.ok) throw new Error(data.failure);

    return data;
  },
);

export const getAppointments = createAsyncThunk(
  'appointments/getAppointments',
  async () => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    const response = await fetch(`${API}/appointments`, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    });
    if (!response.ok) throw new Error(response.statusText);
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
  },
);

export const appointmentsSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'appointments',
  initialState: {
    loading: false,
    error: null,
    data: [],
  },
  extraReducers: {
    [postAppointments.pending]: (state) => {
      state.loading = true;
    },
    [postAppointments.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = action.error.message;
    },
    [postAppointments.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.data.push(action.payload);
    },
    [getAppointments.pending]: (state) => {
      state.loading = true;
    },
    [getAppointments.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.error = action.error.message;
    },
    [getAppointments.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.data = action.payload;
    },

  },
});

export default appointmentsSlice.reducer;
```

src/components/Appointments

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Link, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { getAppointments } from '../redux/appointmentsSlice';

const Appointments = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { data: user } = useSelector((state) => state.user);

  const appointments = useSelector((state) => state.appointments);
  console.log('appointments', appointments);

  const { data, loading } = appointments;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      dispatch(getAppointments());
    }
  }, []);

  if (!user) {
    return <Redirect to="/Login" />;
  }

  return (
    <div className="container text-center">
      <h3>Appointments</h3>
      {loading && <span className="spinner-border spinner-border-lg" />}
      <div className="d-flex flex-wrap">
        {(!loading && data.length === 0)
        && (
        <h4>
          You do not have any appointment. Create one
          <Link to="/appointments/new">
            here
          </Link>
        </h4>
        )}
      </div>
      {
      data && data.map((appointment) => {
        const d = new Date(appointment.appointment_date);
        const date = d.toUTCString();
        return (
          <Link to={`/appointments/${appointment.id}`} key={appointment.id}>
            <div className="card m-4">
              <div className="card-body">
                <p>
                  On &nbsp;
                  {date}
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Link>
        );
      })
  }
    </div>

  );
};

export default Appointments;
```

src/components/NewAppointment

```
/* eslint-disable camelcase */
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { postAppointments } from '../redux/appointmentsSlice';
import { getDoctors } from '../redux/doctorsSlice';

const NewAppointment = () => {
  const [appointmentDate, setAppointmentDate] = useState('');
  const [doctorId, setDoctorId] = useState('');
  const [successful, setSuccessful] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const { data: userData } = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  const { user_id } = userData;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { data, error } = useSelector((state) => state.doctors);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (data === null && userData) {
      dispatch(getDoctors())
        .then(() => {
          loading(false);
        })
        .catch(() => {
        });
    }
  }, [data, dispatch]);

  const onChangeDoctorId = (e) => {
    const doctorId = e.target.value;
    setDoctorId(doctorId);
  };

  const onChangeAppointmentDate = (e) => {
    const appointmentDate = e.target.value;
    setAppointmentDate(appointmentDate);
  };

  const doctor_id = doctorId;
  const appointment_date = appointmentDate;

  const handleBooking = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setSuccessful(false);

    // eslint-disable-next-line no-underscore-dangle

    dispatch(postAppointments({
      user_id, doctor_id, appointment_date,
    }))
      .then(() => {
        setSuccessful(true);
        alert.show('Appointment created', {
          type: 'success',
          timeout: 2000,
        });
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.message);
        setSuccessful(false);
      });
  };

  const options = data && (
    data.map((doctor) => (
      <option
        key={doctor.id}
        value={doctor.id}
      >
        {doctor.name}
      </option>
    ))
  );

  if (!userData) {
    return <Redirect to="/Login" />;
  }
  if (successful) {
    return <Redirect to="/appointments" />;
  }

  return (
    <div className="col-md-12">
      <div className="card card-container">
        <form onSubmit={handleBooking}>
          { !successful && (
          <div>
            <div className="form-group create">
              <label htmlFor="appointmentDate" className="control-label">
                Appointment Date
                <input
                  type="date"
                  className="form-control"
                  name="appointmentDate"
                  id="appointmentDate"
                  required
                  value={appointmentDate}
                  onChange={onChangeAppointmentDate}
                />
              </label>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group create">
              <label htmlFor="doctorId">
                Select from list:
                <select className="form-control" id="doctorId" onChange={onChangeDoctorId} value={doctorId}>
                  {loading ? <option>Loading..</option> : options }
                </select>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group create">
              <button className="btn btn-primary btn-block" disabled={loading} type="submit">
                {loading && (
                <span className="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" />
                )}
                <span>Book</span>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          )}
          {error && (
          <div className="form-group">
            <div className={successful ? 'alert alert-success' : 'alert alert-danger'} role="alert">
              {error}
            </div>
          </div>
          )}
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default NewAppointment;
```

src/redux/store

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import doctorsReducer from './doctorsSlice';
import appointmentsReducer from './appointmentsSlice';
import userReducer from './userSlice';
import typeReducer from './typeSlice';
import doctorReducer from './doctorSlice';

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    doctors: doctorsReducer,
    appointments: appointmentsReducer,
    user: userReducer,
    type: typeReducer,
    doctor: doctorReducer,

  },
});
```

[redux store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsqLB.png)

I know the issue is with my rails-api. All my several changes couldn't fix the issue. I have implemeted solutions with similar issues from and outside this platform, but none solved my issue.
I really don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: Check the value of ${id}, looks empty or not set.

Comment: @Grumpy, yes it's flagging it as `undefined`. But why?. I guess I have added it the right way. With ${id} now a variable that will automatically take the id value of the get data from the store. This is my line of thought. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Where are you dispatching `postAppointments`?

Comment: @ksav to the redux store.

Comment: It's not visible anywhere in your example.

Comment: @ksav, I have added the store above. And also a link to the image. Currently, the action is been rejected because of the `error`

Comment: @ksav, I can successfully create appointments on `postman`. Which is an indication that the backend is fine. Correct me if I'm wrong. I just recreated one now.

Comment: What happens if you `console.log({ user_id, doctor_id, appointment_date })` in the top of `handleBooking`?

Comment: I get this: user_id => 1, doctor_id => 1, and appointment_date => 2021-08-05

Comment: `if @appointment.update(appointment_params)` could be falsy in `AppointmentsController`. What does that mean?

Comment: It means we can only update three params which are `user_id`, `doctor_id` and `appointment_date`. Any other params will make it falsy or throw an error.    So, this from the log: `"appointment"=>{"appointment_date"=>"2021-08-04", "doctor_id"=>"", "user_id"=>20}` is not suppose to be part of the parameters. I don't what is generating it from the react-redux end.

Comment: `Unpermitted parameter: :appointment`. Where does this come from?

Comment: @ksav, `appointment` is not part of the `appointment_param`. Hence the error: `Unpermitted parameter: :appointment`. But what I'm finding difficult to figure out is, what's generating it from the front-end. I have checked all my appointments components, especially the `NewAppointment` and I can't find where.

Comment: Where does it come from if it's not being posted by the fetch in `postAppointments`? Check your browser console to inspect the XHR request.

Comment: Initially, I thought it was the `token`. I removed the token. So if I'm fetching data, I use the `local-storage.getItem('token')` to get the token since the token is stored in my local storage for logged-in user. But the error still persists. I still don't know where it's coming from.

Comment: Check your browser console to inspect the XHR request being sent. See if `postAppointments` is posting only the permitted params. If it is, start logging values in your rails controller.

Comment: @ksav, XHR request indicates the `error` is of type `Fetch`.

Comment: So no params are being sent with the request?

Comment: I can't see any params with it.

Comment: Is it being created in `AppointmentsController`?

Comment: @ksav, hmmm....I don't think so. The `AppointmentsController` `create action` looks ok to me.

Answer (score 0):

[createAsyncThunk - Payload creator](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#payloadcreator)

> The payloadCreator function will be called with two arguments:
>
> 1. `arg`: a single value, containing the first parameter that was passed to the thunk action creator when it was dispatched. This is useful for passing in values like item IDs that may be needed as part of the request. If you need to pass in multiple values, pass them together in an object when you dispatch the thunk, like `dispatch(fetchUsers({status: 'active', sortBy: 'name'}))`.
> 2. `thunkAPI`: an object containing all of the parameters that are normally passed to a Redux thunk function, as well as additional options...

---

Ensure you are calling your action creators correctly. For example,  `getAppointments` accepts a single argument, an object with `id` and `jwt` keys. e.g.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (user) {
    dispatch(getAppointments({ id: user.user_id, jwt: 'somevalue' }));
  }
}, []);
```

Similarly, `postAppointments` accepts a single argument, an object with `user_id`, `appointment_date`, `doctor_id` and `jwt` keys. e.g.

```
dispatch(postAppointments({ 
  user_id: 'somevalue',
  appointment_date: 'somevalue',
  doctor_id: 'somevalue',
  jwt: 'somevalue',
}));
```

I would imagine that without a valid jwt on the request, your api would return `401 (Unauthorized)`

Comment: I implemented the above solution. But I'm getting `jwt` to be `undefined` for `getAppointments` action creator. However, I get the right `jwt` for the `postAppointments` action creator. Here's I implemented it: `const { data: user, jwt } = useSelector((state) => state.user);`   ```useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      dispatch(getAppointments({ id: user.user_id, jwt }));
      console.log('id', user.user_id);
      console.log('jwt', jwt);
    }
  }, []);
```             I think I'm missing something

Comment: What do these two lines log? `console.log("id", user.user_id) console.log("jwt", jwt)`